# Does the right against self incrimination mean you can't be forced to file a tax return?

Tags: tax-law, constitutional-law, us-constitution, fifth-amendment

Irwin Schiff claims that because you have a right against self incrimination and therefore it is wrong for you to have to reveal anything about what you make.  Therefore, the government can levy the tax on income, but various forms and other revealing info should not be allowed.

Is this true?

Comment: As someone mentioned on another question about him: "Irwin Schiff was tried and convicted of tax fraud three separate times, served multiple prison sentences, and *died in prison*. Why anyone would consider him a reliable source of legal advice is beyond my comprehension."

Comment: Legal advice?  I wouldnt take his advice.  What I am wondering is whether his arguments are sound.  To illustrate my point, obviously it is bad advice to tell someone to, say, try to violently overthrow the government by themselves.  That doesn't mean that it is morally wrong to do so.  It would depend on the government, for one thing.

Comment: @nomen agentis.  The rules for posting here suggest that subjective questions are permissible under certain conditions, which I believe I have met.  Instead of focusing on one subject, the fifth amendment, I have instead opened the entire set of topic Irwin Schiff has covered to the same question.

Comment: @nomen agentis - Or it could be answered by one person who phrased it as "Some may say that this means that, while others have said that this means this.  At the end of the day the courts have said this means this, but there was one on the bench who dissented."

Comment: @Mr.A - I just reverted your changes.  You can't make such substantive changes to a question after it has been answered.  If you want to ask about other arguments then please do so with new questions.

Comment: @feetwet.  But I am not the one who edited it in the first place.  The way it is now is the way the question was originally worded.  Then nomen came along and changed it and answered it before I could change it back

Comment: @Mr.A - *nomen agentis* made it answerable and on-topic.  He is correct that such a broad question as you seem to want to pose would not be appropriate here.  If you don't like what was done with this question you're welcome to try again with a different question.  (You can even disclaim ownership of this question by using the "contact us" form.)  NB: If you want to submit further questions along these lines you ought to first peruse the "frivolous tax arguments" law [mentioned here](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/4566/10).

Comment: Interesting side note: In Germany, if you're not self employed and have the standard tax class, you don't have to file your taxes. The tax office already got your standard taxes from your employer. Many people file their taxes anyway, because that's usually better than the standard tax, but you don't have to do anything. Now if you're self-employed, the tax office needs you to declare how much you earned that year so you need to file taxes. Or if you chose a different tax class than your standard one or filed for any exemptions, you have to show that you paid the right amount, so file taxes.

Comment: @Sumyrda: And if you don't file your taxes, they estimate how much you earned. If you pay without filing or complaining, they draw the conclusion that the estimate was too low (elementary, dear Watson) and increase the estimate.

Comment: And since Mr. Schiff was concerned with self incrimination, if you have illegal income (say a million Euros from a bank robbery), you are expected to come to the Inland Revenue and tell them that you have a million Euro one-time income from a source that you don't wish to divulge, and they will tax you accordingly. No self incrimination needed.

Answer (score 15):

Since you asked, and it's a perfectly legitimate question, here's *why* it doesn't violate the Fifth Amendment (from *Garner v. US*):

The Fifth Amendment doesn't say "you can't be made to say anything that hurts you." It says "no person...shall be compelled in any *criminal case* to be a witness against himself." The *only* time Fifth Amendment protection applies is if you are being forced by the government to make a statement that could open you up to an accusation or conviction of a criminal offense. It's fairly broad (if it would help prove any aspect of the charge, you can claim immunity), but it's also restricted (you can't claim it unless it really *would* tend to incriminate you).

That means that you could only argue the Fifth Amendment if your tax return might help prove a criminal case against you (the fact that disclosing income leads to you needing to pay tax does not qualify as "self-incrimination"). But the *amount* of income is not one of those things that might incriminate you -- you can get income through all sorts of ways. The thing that is incriminating is revealing the *source* of the income, and you can claim Fifth Amendment privilege for that.

So:

- The only time you could possibly claim privilege is if you were being forced into a statement that might tend to incriminate you in a criminal proceeding. A statement that makes you liable for tax doesn't mean it might incriminate you.
- Filing an income tax return isn't inherently incriminating. The fact that you have income not included in any other part of the return (illegal income goes under "other income") doesn't imply you've committed a crime -- lots of people have other income.
- The *amount* of income can't be incriminating. The *source* can be, but you can claim Fifth Amendment privilege for that if it might incriminate you. And lawful income under "other income" still might give rise to a reasonable fear of prosecution, so the fact that you're justified in claiming Fifth Amendment privilege in source of income doesn't mean you're guilty of a crime.

Note that there are cases where you *are* flat-out exempt from filing tax returns under the Fifth Amendment: *Marchetti v. US* and *Grosso v. US* found that registration and tax on gambling *could* be blocked by a Fifth Amendment claim, which didn't even have to be asserted at time of filing, because merely filing the special return would establish you as a gambler (heavily regulated/often criminalized at the state level). The difference with the normal income tax form is that *everyone* (just about) files one, and so filing it doesn't mean you're a criminal. If there was a separate line along the lines of "Income from Illegal Drug Sales," that might be one thing (anything other than $0 is inherently incriminating). But all the questions are broad, and have many legal sources of income associated with them.

Comment: I think if this answer were combined with nomen's answer, it would be pretty good

Comment: Except I'd like to make sure its clear whether you mean what you say is what those justices reasoned, or if it is your reasoning.

Comment: NVM Maybe I missed your citations...or maybe you edited your post.  I'm thinking about approving this answer

Comment: This is based off the *Garner* opinion (and the edit off *Marchetti* and *Grosso*, cited in *Garner*), although the part about what the Fifth Amendment means is just what the Fifth Amendment means (it says in the amendment "in criminal cases").

Comment: What happens in a case of benefit fraud? If you received benefits because you claimed you had no income, then filing your tax return showing lots of money _would_ incriminate you?

Comment: @gnasher729: Good point. That sounds like a good question (hint :-) ).

Answer (score 10):

There is no support for Schiff's position that the Fifth Amendment allows you to withhold from the IRS information about your income.

In [*United States v. Sullivan*](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/274/259/case.html) 274 U.S. 259 (1927), the unanimous Supreme Court held that:

> The Fifth Amendment does not protect the recipient of such income from prosecution for willful refusal to make any return under the income tax law.

In *[United States v. Schiff](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar_case?case=9395786726505555671)* 612 F.2d 73 (2d Cir. 1979), the trial judge noted (and the unanimous appeals court panel did not disagree with this point) that:

> the Fifth Amendment does not give a person the right to withhold the required information on the return concerning items the disclosure of which would not incriminate him or tend to incriminate him, and that even as to items which might incriminate him, he is required to state the amount of his income even if he does not reveal its illegal source.

Comment: This is useful, but it is not complete, even if I just wanted the answer about the 5th amendment.  For one thing, it provides only an "appeal to authority" based answer without outlining a basis in statutory/constitutional reasoning.  It doesn't address the appeals of the dissenters.  The courts aren't the final word on whether something is legal or not, they just give force to a dispute.

Comment: I don't know how there can be many valid questions on this site, since most interesting topics are bound to be opinion based.  Unless I wanted to ask clear questions such as "what does Title 1 Section 10 read", or "what did the Warren court say in Texas v. Smith (1950)", I think pretty much any question such as "is X legal" is an opinion.  You are aware that if they appointed me to the supreme court and cut down the number of justices to just one I could easily do away with Marbury Madison, right?

Comment: Every law is an opinion, except it's not an opinion. The role of judges and courts is not to discuss philosophy and whether or not something technically means this, its job is to say 'this means this until we say so otherwise.' If you want to change this then you should try to influence the supreme court in some way, but until that happens this is your answer.

Comment: @Mr.A Your point being? If the Supreme Court overturned Marbury v. Madison, then that would become binding precedent (briefly). Likewise, if all 538 members of the Electoral College decide to disregard the popular vote and vote for the coach of the New England Patriots for President, we'd have President Belichick. Except that judges *don't* make wild rulings based only on personal views, and electors *don't* vote for the coaches of sports teams instead of the candidate they pledged to. So, it's useful to look at past court rulings (which are law).

Comment: @cpast - I think the reason I ask questions like this is because what I really want to know is "is this guy really crazy" or "is the government actually kind of tyrannical in some sense."  That's why, here, I wanted to be able to look past what a judge said, because knowing what the judge said doesnt tell me whether or not the judge was tyrannical.

Comment: In any case, if the answerer could distill the actual reasoning behind those court cases, I might find the answer more acceptable.

Comment: I second what Mr. A said. I want to know the reasoning too. Someone can go steal something and say NOTHING to anyone. Yet you can work productively as programmers and have to confess to some government agency. Why?

Comment: @cpast: What Marbury v. Madison actually says is that legitimate court decisions sometimes require that judges say what the law is, implying a causal relationship between the law and what the judges write.  While court decisions are *presumed* legitimate, that does not mean that the law magically becomes whatever the NIne declare it to be.  If the Nine decide to ignore the Constitution, there may be no recognized means by which their words can be recognized as being lawless, but that doesn't make them lawful.

Comment: @Mr.A: I think questions like "is this guy crazy" or "is the government tyrannical" are beyond the scope of Law.SE.  I believe it's a generally accepted principle in law that courts determine how laws are to be interpreted and applied, and that their decisions have the force of law.  If that isn't the definition of the word "legal" that you want to use, then the burden shifts to you to precisely define what "legal" means for you, and then the community can decide whether your interpretation is on-topic for this site.

Comment: @nate I would interpret these questions as more of a "are these arguments legally sound", because there's a million ways to read questions, and we should necessarily be reading them as being about the law. Let's discuss the legal questions, not the individuals that advance them (unless that is necessary to the question). "Is the government tyrannical" is more of a political question I think, so I would tend to agree that those probably aren't on-topic here, but some aspects of it might be. A meta discussion like this probably deserves it's own post on [meta], though...

Comment: @Mr.A What exactly are you looking for?  You mention in a comment you would like someone to "distill the actual reasoning behind those court cases."  In the first case link I clicked, there was a synopsis providing exactly that.  If the content of the synopsis is insufficient, then you may need to be very clear with what you expect to see (possibly in a different question), because you are likely asking for a very specific thing that others have not felt needed to be summarized in that form.

Comment: If the question is "is every one of the many judges who have all unanimously held the exact same opinion, every time it has come across the courtroom tyrannical," and you seek something besides their words and actions to judge by, then that might be a different question.  Perhaps for the philosophy SE, rather than law SE.  The wording starts to sound like more of an ethical question in such a case.